# After creating own cocoapods library, when pod install my pod, There is only ReplaceMe.m file

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

I created my own cocoapods library and push it. But when i run `pod install` for an app, there is only `ReplaceMe.m` file. But i have changed this file with my own classes. And also i can see files on github.

```
platform :'ios', '8.0'

pod 'MyPod'
```

However, if i add git url to Podfile, Library classes exist.

```
platform :'ios', '8.0'

pod 'MyPod', :git => 'https://github.com/ugurcetinkaya/MyPod.git'
```

What should i do to solve this?

My .podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'UURCCentralizedTokenView'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'Customizable Centralized TokenView'
  s.description      = 'Customizable Centralized TokenView for iOS applications.'

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/ugurcetinkaya/UURCCentralizedTokenView'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Ugur Cetinkaya' => 'ugurcetinkaya@ymail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/ugurcetinkaya/UURCCentralizedTokenView.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.source_files = 'UURCCentralizedTokenView/Classes/**/*'

  s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
```

Comment: Post you pod spec file!

Comment: I added to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. Git version of library didn't have library classes on current release. I added classes to my repo. After that i updated version of my repo and my pod with adding new tag to my repo. Cocoapods version is looking at the version of repo.